# Deploy a war file in the application?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jamon

I am trying to integrate the monitoring tool `JAMon` into my current Spring application. Everything is fine except I don't know how to establish the monitoring information on UI or log file. What is more confusing, is from [here](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/log4j_jamonappender.html)
under the section "Setting up the JAMonAppender - Default Behaviour", I see this line:

> Install JAMon.war in your application, so you can view your Log4J
>   statistics and log records.

is there anyway that I can install a war file in current application or there is something wrong with above description?

My understanding is the war file should deployed in an application server. Can I use it as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is the war file should deployed in an application
>   server. Can I use it as a dependency?

Any WAR file **must** be deployed in an application container. It cannot be used as a dependency. For your sake, you missed point 1, where you can download the API with all its dependencies [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamonapi/files/).